# First appearance of the shtick of mutants who are shunned?

Tags: history-of, mutant

I just finished reading The Chrysalids, a 1955 book by John Wyndham about a world after a nuclear apocalypse in which people superstitiously kill or exile mutants.

The idea of ionizing radiation causing scary or weird mutations is obviously one of the most commonly occurring SFnal ideas of the 1950's. Wyndham's idea of people shunning or exiling the mutants also doesn't seem to have been at all trailblazing at the time, since Heinlein did the same thing in the 1941 Orphans of the Sky.

Was Heinlein the first to come up with the shun-the-mutants shtick? 1941 actually seems surprisingly early for this idea.

As late as 1946, John Hersey's book Hiroshima seems to have surprised the general public by documenting the fact that ionizing radiation could kill people. (Lesley M.M. Blume recently published a book about this.)

Clarification: This question is specifically about mutations induced by high levels of ionizing radiation.

Comment: I'm thinking Well's The Time Machine (1895) - Eloi vs Morlocks

Comment: *Slan*? *Odd John*?

Comment: @user14111 I was also thinking *Slan*, or alternatively the were from Williamson's *Darker Than You Think*.  (Both would have an original publication date of 1940.)

Comment: Not as early as Heinlein, but E.C. Tubb's *The Mutants Rebel* from 1953 is interesting because it uses the term *homo superior* for mutants with mental abilities - perhaps the first instance of this use. https://www.risingshadow.net/library/book/5021-the-mutants-rebel

Comment: People who are different (especially from genetic mutation) have been shunned for all of human history. The first SciFi example should be very close to the first ever SciFi.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen The term *Homo superior* was used in Olaf Stapledon's 1935 novel *Odd John*.

Comment: @user14111 Ah, thank you! I have read a few Stapledon books, but not that one.

Answer (score 4):

**Shunning the Mutantz** is as old a schtick as you can get in literature of many genres.  Simply because it's a normal through broken human reaction to fear the unknown, and thus kill it (at worst) or send it away (at best).

Off hand, shunning the mutant is a major theme in the *Hunchback of Notre Dame* (Victor Hugo, 1831).  It's a theme in various Gospels, shunning the lepers, e.g. (God, 32).  It's a theme in the Epic of Gilgamesh (Emegir., 2100BC)

Comment: lol, "God, 32" nice citation :)

Comment: @NKCampbell -- Well, we like proper literary citations around here!

Comment: A leper isn't a mutant, they're a person with a disease. A person with a hunchback may or may not have it because of a genetic cause. Genetic disease does not have to be a mutation; it can be a bad recessive gene. Re Gilgamesh, if you're referring to Enkidu, he isn't a mutant, he's a guy with a lot of hair created by a goddess. I've added a note to the question to clarify that it really is meant to be limited to mutations caused by high levels of ionizing radiation.

Comment: @BenCrowell -- You're suffering from modernism! They are when you don't know what leprosy is. I know you mean "mutant" in the ultra modern context, where readers know a little about genetics and genetic mutations etc and also that leprosy is a bacterial infection. Keep in mind that earlier generations did not have our advanced understanding!

Comment: While amusing, "God, 32" is inaccurate on two counts. Try "Mark, 70".